# How can I setup a development environment which auto refresh page when code have changed

Tags: customization

When develop a website with Wordpress, I spent a lot of time to change small pieces of code like CSS, HTML element.

Each time I did that, I needed to do so many steps:

1. Change the code
2. Save it
3. Switch to web page window
4. Refresh the web page
5. Check the updated content

I had 2 monitors in my workspace.
So I wish that have some technical help me just save the code then web page will auto refresh.

After that, I just have 3 steps:

1. Change the code
2. Save it
3. Check the updated content

Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: This is definitely possible...node.js or browswersyc can start you in the right direction, but it's way out of scope for this stack.

Comment: I did this before with static HTML project by using node.js. I guess we need a specific technique to do the same thing with Wordpress so I asked for help. I find out that BrowserSync is a perfect solution in this case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like BrowserSync is what you're looking for ( https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-browsersync-for-faster-development )

Comment: I did some research and it's work perfect. More than I expected. Thank you so much!